# I am trying to get the characters after the last delimiter / dax only solution please

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
ResName = IFERROR(Mid('Hellodetails'[resourceId],Find("/",'Hellodetails'[resourceId],1)),BLANK())
```

Column =

```
/subscriptions/3e5b4f75-12834/rgs/-test1-rg/providers/microsoft.web/sites/re2-test1

/subscriptions/3e5b4f75-12834/rgs/-test1-rg/providers/microsoft.web/sites/groups/re2-test1-wa-asset

/subscriptions/3e5b4f75-12834/rgs/-test1-rg/providers/microsoft.web/sites/r/re2-test1-wa-product
```

**Output**

```
re2-test1

re2-test1-wa-asset

re2-test1-wa-product
```

This is what I am trying to get but I am not geeting the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a column with your desired output, using Power Query M-Code (not DAX):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("rc09DoMwDEDhuzDXWPypvQtiIMFEHlpHtlOuT6QuZWf/9N48N2glWFTOzvIxHGgK4/6coOtfw4iaDMHJvANNmFW+vJEavjmqmOzeHhTQuBJU6n+0WR53dpNKyX95OFZYzchv/uh1UfFWYp0sJw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

    lastDelimited = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Last Part", 
        each List.Last(Text.Split([Column1],"/")), Text.Type)
in
    lastDelimited
```

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

***Using DAX***

```
    Column = TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([Column1],"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Comment: I am not able to use powerquery for some reason because the data needs credentials so the only way is dax for me im guessing

Comment: @JackDis I added a DAX formula that seems to work OK here.